# How to handle mongodb aggregation fields in typeORM

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

this.repo is a MongoRepository, and I want to use an aggregation pipeline for counting something:

```
this.repo.aggregateEntity([{
      $group: {
        _id: {country: "$country"},
        country: {$first: "$country"},
        count: {$sum: 1}
      }
    }])
```

I never get back the **count** field. So I tried a plenty of things, eg. followed the advice to add the count column to entity definition without metadata:

```
  ...
  @Index()
  @Column()
  country: string;

  count: number;
  ...
```

Nothing was working.
How can I get the count field in my result?

Comment: Try to execute `.aggregate` instead of `.aggregateEntity`

Comment: Can you share collection ?

Comment: @Valijon - great, I wasn't aware of .aggregate. Thank you very much, that is working. If you like to answer here, I can mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MongoRepository.aggregate](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/classes/_repository_mongorepository_.mongorepository.html#aggregate) executes an aggregation framework pipeline against the collection. This returns each result as is.

`MongoRepository.aggregateEntity` executes an aggregation framework pipeline against the collection. This returns modified version of cursor that transforms each result into `Entity` model. If your `Entity` model doesn't have a result field, it won't be populated

```
//https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/51b2a63d/src/repository/MongoRepository.ts#L130
return this.manager.aggregateEntity(this.metadata.target, pipeline, options);
```